# Kafka Streams: What are the negative consequences of having a slow punctuate job?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

In our Kafka Streams topology, we have some punctuates, that may take a long time to run (several minutes).

What are the consequences of having such slow punctuates? Will the process in which they run stop processing records while punctuate runs? Can they cause re-balances to happen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if your punctuator logic runs slowly like several minutes, Kafka stream will not consume new messages from specific partition (on which punctuator is executed) until punctuator completes execution. also long running punctuator shouldn't trigger rebalancing (rebalancing might occur due to other reasons)

whether punctuator on one partition affects others depends on whether you run application on single node or on multiple, and also on `num.stream.threads` property that you might specified for Kafka Streams. 
if your app is running on a single node, Kafka stream will use only single thread for all partitions (by default, `num.stream.threads` is 1). so in this case punctuator on specific partition blocks all other partitions as well. but in case you have multiple app instances and/or `num.stream.threads` greater than 1, if some of punctuators run quickly, then such partitions will not be affected from long running punctuators on other partitions.

Comment: "long running punctuator shouldn't trigger rebalancing" -- just wanted to add on this. It depends on the `max.poll.interval.ms` configuration: as long as a punctuation is executed, `poll()` will not be called and thus, it would be possible to hit this timeout -- however, in Kafka Streams the default config is set to `MAX_VALUE`, ie, as long as you don't change the config, this should never happen.

Comment: But I/O timeout could still happen of the punctuator tries to write to a topic, this in my case killed the thread, and hence triggered rebalancing